# Math captcha using ASCII, is it safe?

Tags: security, ascii, captcha

I had to put a captcha on my form. In favor of user-friendliness and internationalization I went with a simple math question.

Since that's almost too simple for bots to crack, I decided to put the entire question in ASCII. Is this relatively safe or can it still be easily bypassed by most bots?

I have: & #87; & #104;& #97;& #116;  & #105;...  and it will output "What is 4 + 1?"

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to parse through this text and solve the captcha with a bot. You should use an image captcha.

Comment: It will be safe to an extent. But if your site gets popular, bots will figure it out

Comment: Cole and @CameronTinker Thanks a lot for your insights. I had no idea... I guess I have to do something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate an image of the math question instead. And probably apply some simple transformations if you need more security.

The HTML escape is easy to bypass as it is a computer readable format. For a bot detections scheme to be successful the task must be easy for a computer to generate, easy for a human to solve, and difficult for computer to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's exactly what I wanted to know.